A question about Hilbert Theorem 90 and Artin-Schreier Theorem
I'm reading Lang's "Algebra" and there's a passage in the proof of Theorem 6.3 pg.290 (namely Hilbert's Theorem 90 additive form) for which I can't find a justification, if anyone could provide an explanation, I would appreciate it.
This theorem is used for recovering Artin-Schreier Theorem for cyclic extensions in characteristic p (so, even if not explicitly stated in the theorem, the hypothesis of characteristic p can be assumed if necessary). The precise statement of the theorem is the following:
"Let $K/F$ be a cyclic field extension of degree $n$, $\sigma$ be a generator of the Galois group $\text{Gal}(K/F)$ and $\beta\in K$. Then, the trace $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\beta)=0$ if and only if there is an element $\alpha\in K$ s.t. $\beta=\alpha-\sigma(\alpha)$."
Here, by $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\beta)$ we mean the trace of the matrix representation of the $F$-linear map given by the multiplication by $\beta$ in $K$, seen as $F$-vector space (clearly, with respect to some fixed basis).
The unclear passage of the proof is direction $[\Rightarrow]$, in which it is claimed without any further explanation the existence of some $\theta\in K$ s.t. $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\theta)\neq 0$. Do you see why this is the case?

You might want to check out Grillet's book Abstract Algebra for details like this that Lang sometimes annoyingly omits.

Thank you for the nice suggestion ;)

Here is a more hands-on argument avoiding the normal basis theorem. I assume you know this, but just to state the difficulty clearly for a general audience: we of course always have $\text{tr}_{K/F}(1) = n$, which settles the question in any characteristic not dividing $n$. However, for Artin-Schreier theory we need to apply this result in characteristic $p$ and when $n = p$, so we can't get away with this and we need to find some other element.
We can instead use primitive elements. Let $\alpha \in K$ be a primitive element, so that $\{ 1, \alpha, \dots \alpha^{n-1} \}$ is a basis for $K$ over $F$. Then there is some element of $K$ with nonzero trace iff $\text{tr}_{K/F}(\alpha^k) \neq 0$ for some $0 \le k \le n-1$, so let's try to prove this. These traces are the sums of the powers of the conjugates of $\alpha$, namely
$$\text{tr}_{K/F}(\alpha^k) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sigma^i \alpha)^k$$
and we have the nice result that if $x_1, \dots x_n$ are elements of any field of characteristic $0$ such that the power sum symmetric functions $p_k = \sum x_i^k$ are all zero, then the $x_i$ are all zero, using Newton's identities to express the elementary symmetric functions $e_k$ of the $x_i$ in terms of the power sums.
But Newton's identities express $ke_k$ as an integer polynomial in the smaller $e_i$ and $p_i$, so in characteristic $p$ what we get is that $e_k = 0$ for all $k$ not divisible by $p$ but not necessarily otherwise. If $p \mid n$ (which as above is the interesting case) it follows that if the traces $\text{tr}_{K/F}(\alpha^k)$ are all zero then the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{\alpha}(t)$ of $\alpha$ is a polynomial in $t^p$, and such a polynomial cannot be irreducible. Taking the contrapositive, some trace does not vanish.
This argument does not require $K/F$ to be cyclic or even Galois; we actually get the result assuming separability only (in which case we replace the $\sigma^i \alpha$ above with the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$ in a normal closure of $K$). In fact more is true: a finite extension is separable iff the trace form is nondegenerate.

That is because, since $K/F$ is Galois, there exists $\vartheta\in K$ such that the family $(\sigma(\vartheta))_{\sigma\in{\rm Gal}(K/F)}$ is an $F$-basis of $K$. Now,
$$ {\rm Tr}_{F/K}(\vartheta)=\sum_{\sigma\in{\rm Gal}(K/F)}\sigma(\vartheta) $$
can't be $0$ because this is a non-trivial linear combination composed of vectors of a free family. Note that the fact that $K/F$ is cyclic is not used here.
